# GoLang: есть ли доступ к железу?

Tags: golang

Думаю вот новый проект начать на go. Нет возможности сильно его изучить и разобраться до начала работы. А этот момент определит, упадёт ли выбор на go или стандартно на Java в сцепке с С++. Хотелось бы на go.

Внутренний заказчик к нашим системам требует, чтобы на сервисах была элементарная защита от копирования. Получить бы серийники, или какие-нибудь жесткие данные железа. Понятно, что инженер всё это пере-раз-ди-ассемблит и разберется... Но необходимости защитить от инженера нет, есть необходимость защитить от контент-менеджера. Ну чтобы совсем простаками не выглядеть.

Если не получится напрямую запросить, то буду рад какой-нить библиотечке, которая проглотит С++ без лишних забот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт серийников не уверен, но взять MAC-адреса можно и средствами стандартной библиотеки:

```golang
ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("can't get interfaces: %s", err)
}

for _, iface := range ifaces {
    fmt.Printf("%16s = %16s\n", iface.Name, iface.HardwareAddr)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-ikp9ws3164.

Для контент-менеджера должно хватить.

Comment: Чорт... Этот язык идеален... >_< Я влюбится.